# Is it ok to keep a filewriter open all the time?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-file

i read that opening and closing a filewriter can be a little heavy operation. So is it ok to keep a filewriter open all the time ?

Comment: What is all the time?

Comment: Where did you read this? Are you actually solving any performance issues?

Comment: k.krol: i just ask, don't remember where i read it, maybe here on so - tnw All the time is all the life of the service

Comment: Why don't you test the performance yourself? From the standpoint of data integrity, I would rather that you close the `FileWriter` when you are not actively writing to the file.

Comment: Your friendly **mantra**: *"open it, use it, **close it**"*

Comment: hard to test the performance, especially that i m also concerned about battery life. I think i will not detect anything noticeable so everything is pure theory

Answer (score 3):

By keeping it open you may have to worry about integrity as CommonsWare pointed out in the comments of your question. The only reason I see for doing so would be to reduce time it takes to open correct? That isn't much time that is required so from a safety perspective you would be much better off just closing it when you are done actively writing to the file and re-opening when needed rather then keeping it open for the lifetime of your app.

Answer (score 2):

If "all the time" means for the duration of your program, then the answer is *yes*. The purpose of closing a file writer is to be sure all data written to a file is written to the file. When writing, optimizations are taken to make the I/O process quicker, so the OS will often take a write a request and write it to a cache or buffer, then when that buffer is full it'll bulk write all the contents to the file as one I/O, rather than possible hundreds. Closing a file writer flushes this buffer by telling the OS to write the buffer to the file, even though it may not be full. In most cases, exiting a program will auto close any readers/writers open, but it is always best practice to explicitly write the close line as explicit is always better than implicit.

This is not all closing a writer does, but it is the bulk of the reason for doing so. Closing writers also end the channel open to that file, so for security reasons you should close writers when not in use. The only reason calling open/close is expensive is because you make an I/O when doing so. So if you can eliminate calls (ie calling open/close outside a loop rather than within) that would be beneficial, but don't feel like you need one open and one close for life time of that writer's usage.